# Word2Vec add letter "s" to chinese

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, word2vec

I am working on  a project which is use LSTM to classify the chinsese text. I chose word2vec to represent the text and fit in LSTM.
This is my code:

```py
import gensim
DIM=100
w2vec_model=gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences=cop3,size=DIM,window=10,min_count=1)

##tokenize
tokenizer=Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(cop3)
X=tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(cop3)

# add padding
max_len=30
X=pad_sequences(X,maxlen=max_len)

# create vocabulary
vocab_size=len(tokenizer.word_index)+1
vocab=tokenizer.word_index

#to get the weight of each word in vocabulary
def get_weight(model):
  weight_martrix=np.zeros((vocab_size,DIM))
  for word,i in vocab.items():
        weight_martrix[i]=model.wv[word]
    
  return weight_martrix

embeeding=get_weight(w2vec_model)
```

And then I got error: KeyError

> Traceback (most recent call last)  in
> ()
> ----> 1 embeeding=get_weight(w2vec_model)
>
> 3 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py
> in word_vec(self, word, use_norm)
> 450             return result
> 451         else:
> --> 452             raise KeyError("word '%s' not in vocabulary" % word)
> 453
> 454     def get_vector(self, word):
>
> KeyError: "word '大s' not in vocabulary"

Does anyone know why they letter "s" was added to my word ? And how to fix that?

Comment: Could be related to the word encoding you are using for `cop3`.

Answer (score 0):

This error actually suggests that the version of the word inside your `tokenizer.word_index` sequence may include that `s`. (The error suggests such a token **did not** appear in the `Word2Vec` steps, and thus it has no entry for that word.)

So: you should slim your analysis/example to just the creation & examination of the `tokenizer`, to see whether its results are sensible. (As the actual source of the `Tokenizer` class is unshown, it's hard to speculate about what might be going wrong there. But also slimming down your corpus to the smallest, or single, text that displays the problem may also help.)

Separately: note that `min_count=1` in `Word2Vec` is almost always a bad idea. The algorithm only works well for words with many varied usage examples - and actually improves on remaining words, when you discard very-low-frequency words.